# Selenium Basic VBA Copying Date from Webpage to Excel Randomly Swapping Day and Month

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium Basic VBA to loop through an Excel table of URLs, open each URL, find a specific date field on that webpage, and return the date as a string to a column on the Excel table.

9 times out of 10 this works perfectly, but seemingly randomly, the date is returned with the day and month swapped, i.e. where the webpage shows "05/11/2019" the Excel column shows "11/05/2019".

When this happens, the date is also right-aligned in Excel, whereas all the others appear as left-aligned. When I edit the left-aligned cells and then select another cell, they then right-align, whereas the right-aligned cells stay the same. This isn't a problem in itself, but I wonder if it holds a clue to the problem.

If it helps at all, this is the VBA code I'm using to extract the data (I've hashed out confidential but irrelevant details in the URL). I'm using Google Chrome as the browser.

I've had to add a `bot.Wait` to give the page time to load and have used `Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim()` as the webpage includes a space after the date string.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data")
    
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("opportunities")
    
    For i = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
        If tbl.ListRows(i).Range(10) = "" Then
            bot.Get "########" & tbl.ListRows(i).Range(1)
            bot.Wait (500)
            tbl.ListRows(i).Range(10) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(bot.FindElementByCss(".l-row-block:nth-child(1) .field:nth-child(7) .value").Text)
        End If
    Next i
```

Any steer on what might be happening here would be very useful!

Comment: It may be because of the excel format, have you tried prepending the date with `'` (single quote)? Something like `Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim("'" & bot.FindElementByCss(".l-row-block:nth-child(1) .field:nth-child(7) .value").Text)`

Comment: @supputuri bingo, that's got it! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please prepend the date with single-quote `'` as shown below.

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim("'" & bot.FindElementByCss(".l-row-block:nth-child(1) .field:nth-child(7) .value").Text)
```